# How to count rows with the same value but different id

Tags: php, mysql, count, union

I have used this sql statement in my database that uses COUNT and UNION ALL

```
SELECT tem.book_id, COUNT( * )
    FROM(SELECT book_id FROM borrowdetails
    WHERE borrowdetails.borrow_status = 'returned'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT book_id from reserve) as tem
    GROUP BY book_id
    ORDER BY book_id DESC
```

then i used this code to name the id in the PHP table

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($user_query)){
    $id=$row['book_id'];
    $book_query = mysql_query("select * from book where book_id = '$id'")or die(mysql_error());
}
```

it works fine but it doesn't unite the data with the same name because it has different id's like this

```
+------+------+-------+
|  id  | name | count |
+------+------+-------+
|1     |A     |   3   | the id here is not shown at the table in PHP just   
+------+------+-------+ inside the database but the A is duplicate.
|2     |A     |   1   |
+------+------+-------+
|3     |B     |   2   |
+------+------+-------+
```

my desired output should be like this without the id showing in the table.

```
+------+-------+
| name | count |
+------+-------+
|A     |   4   |
+------+-------+ this is the table that should be shown in PHP
|B     |   2   |
+------+-------+
```

as you could see the name A's count becomes four because i want also to add the COUNT(*) of both A's.

What am i going to do in order to achieve the desired outcome?

btw this is the db tables that are used.

```
+------+------+     +---------+---------+       +-------+-------+   
|  book table |     |borrowdetails table|       | reserve table |   
+------+------+     +---------+---------+       +-------+-------+   
|  id  | name |     |brw_dt_id| book_id |       |res_id |book_id|
+------+------+     +---------+---------+       +-------+-------+   
|1     |A     |     |    1    |    2    |       |   1   |   1   |
+------+------+     +---------+---------+       +-------+-------+
|2     |A     |     |    2    |    3    |       |   2   |   1   |
+------+------+     +---------+---------+       +-------+-------+
|3     |B     |     |    3    |    3    |       |   3   |   1   |
+------+------+     +---------+---------+       +-------+-------+
```

Comment: GROUP BY book_name instead of GROUP BY book_id?

Comment: select name instead of book_id and also group it by name

Comment: can't do that sir, both reserve and borrowdetails only have book_id the book_name came from the book table.

Comment: Please stop using PHP's deprecated mysql_ API

Comment: what PHP's deprecated mysql_ API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to use book_name rather than using book_id.
I haven't tried this, but it should work

```
Select book_name, count(*) as cnt from books
where book_id IN (
     SELECT book_id FROM borrowdetails
     WHERE borrowdetails.borrow_status = 'returned'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT book_id from reserve
     )
GROUP BY Book_Name
ORDER BY Cnt
```

Comment: but the book_name is not included in borrowdetails it is in another db table so i used  another sql state to name the ID.

Comment: Try this query.  if that does not work, please share the schema of your tables.

Comment: sir @Nikhil thank you so much it works. the problem is solved.

Comment: Not a problem. I am glad it helped. @qaz

Answer (score 0):

We would normally write that this way

```
SELECT book_name
     , count(*) cnt 
  FROM books x
  JOIN
     ( SELECT book_id 
       FROM borrowdetails
      WHERE borrowdetails.borrow_status = 'returned'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT book_id from reserve
     ) y
  ON y.book_id = x.book_id
 GROUP BY Book_Name -- this assumes that book_name is unique 
  ORDER BY Cnt
```

Comment: sir thanks also for showing another type of answer. i used this in another case and it works perfectly.